# JPA - Relationships in compound key identification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**MST151 : TABLE STRUCTURE**

[image]

I want to have an identification relationship as shown in the picture.

**MST151 : Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "MST151")
@Builder
public class MST151 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private String itemId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMP_ID")
    private String compId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRICE_REV")
    private int priceRev;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRICE_TYPE")
    private String priceType;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_STD")
    private double priceStd;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_UNIT")
    private String priceUnit;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_TYPE")
    private String deliveryType;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_DAY")
    private int deleveryDay;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER")
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_USER")
    private String updateUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "USED")
    private int used;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MST110 mst110;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMP_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MST150 mst150;

    public MST151(String itemId, String compId, int priceRev, String priceType, double priceStd, String priceUnit,
            String deliveryType, int deleveryDay, String description, String createUser, Date createTime,
            String updateUser, Date updateTime, int used, MST110 mst110, MST150 mst150) {
        super();
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.compId = compId;
        this.priceRev = priceRev;
        this.priceType = priceType;
        this.priceStd = priceStd;
        this.priceUnit = priceUnit;
        this.deliveryType = deliveryType;
        this.deleveryDay = deleveryDay;
        this.description = description;
        this.createUser = createUser;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        this.used = used;
        this.mst110 = mst110;
        this.mst150 = mst150;
    }
}
```

**MST150 : Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "MST150")
@Builder
public class MST150 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMP_ID")
    private String compId;

    @Column(name = "COMP_NAME")
    private String compName;

    @Column(name = "SALE_YN")
    private int saleYN;

    @Column(name = "PURCHASE_YN")
    private int purchaseYN;

    @Column(name = "OUTSOURCING_YN")
    private int outsourcingYN;

    @Column(name = "DOMESTIC_YN")
    private int domesticYN;

    @Column(name = "DESTRIBUTE_TYPE")
    private String destributeType;

    @Column(name = "BUSINESS")
    private String business;

    @Column(name = "INDUSTRY")
    private String industry;

    @Column(name = "REPRESENTATIVE")
    private String representative;

    @Column(name = "COMP_PHONE")
    private String compPhone;

    @Column(name = "COMP_FAX")
    private String compFax;

    @Column(name = "COMP_EMAIL")
    private String compEmail;

    @Column(name = "POST_NO")
    private String postNo;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "HOMEPAGE")
    private String homepage;

    @Column(name = "MAIN_CHARGE")
    private String mainCharge;

    @Column(name = "CHARGE_PHONE")
    private String chargePhone;

    @Column(name = "CHARGE_CP")
    private String chargeCp;

    @Column(name = "CHARGE_FAX")
    private String chargeFax;

    @Column(name = "CHARGE_EMAIL")
    private String chargeEmail;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER")
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_USER")
    private String updateUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "USED")
    private int used = 0;

    public MST150(String compId, String compName, int saleYN, int purchaseYN, int outsourcingYN, int domesticYN,
            String destributeType, String business, String industry, String representative, String compPhone,
            String compFax, String compEmail, String postNo, String address, String homepage, String mainCharge,
            String chargePhone, String chargeCp, String chargeFax, String chargeEmail, String description,
            String createUser, Date createTime, String updateUser, Date updateTime, int used) {
        super();
        this.compId = compId;
        this.compName = compName;
        this.saleYN = saleYN;
        this.purchaseYN = purchaseYN;
        this.outsourcingYN = outsourcingYN;
        this.domesticYN = domesticYN;
        this.destributeType = destributeType;
        this.business = business;
        this.industry = industry;
        this.representative = representative;
        this.compPhone = compPhone;
        this.compFax = compFax;
        this.compEmail = compEmail;
        this.postNo = postNo;
        this.address = address;
        this.homepage = homepage;
        this.mainCharge = mainCharge;
        this.chargePhone = chargePhone;
        this.chargeCp = chargeCp;
        this.chargeFax = chargeFax;
        this.chargeEmail = chargeEmail;
        this.description = description;
        this.createUser = createUser;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        this.used = used;
    }
}
```

**MST110 : Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MST110")
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class MST110 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private String itemId;

    @Column(name = "ITEM_CODE")
    private String itemCode;

    @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE")
    private String itemType;

    @Column(name = "LOT_SIZE")
    private double lotSize;

    @Column(name = "LOT_UNIT")
    private String lotUnit;

    @Column(name = "SAFETY_QNT")
    private double safetyQnt;

    @Column(name = "SAFETY_UNIT")
    private String safetyUnit;

    @Column(name = "LOC_CODE")
    private String locCode;

    @Column(name = "INV_TYPE")
    private int invType;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER")
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_USER")
    private String updateUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "USED")
    private int used;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mst110", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = true)
    private MST111 mst111;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mst110", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = true)
    private MST112 mst112;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mst110", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = true)
    private MST113 mst113;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mst110", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = true)
    private MST114 mst114;

    public MST110(String itemId, String itemCode, String itemName, String itemType, double lotSize, String lotUnit,
            double safetyQnt, String safetyUnit, String locCode, int invType, String description, String createUser,
            Date createTime, String updateUser, Date updateTime, int used, MST111 mst111, MST112 mst112, MST113 mst113,
            MST114 mst114) {
        super();
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.lotSize = lotSize;
        this.lotUnit = lotUnit;
        this.safetyQnt = safetyQnt;
        this.safetyUnit = safetyUnit;
        this.locCode = locCode;
        this.invType = invType;
        this.description = description;
        this.createUser = createUser;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        this.used = used;
        this.mst111 = mst111;
        this.mst112 = mst112;
        this.mst113 = mst113;
        this.mst114 = mst114;
    }
}
```

Questions :
I want to map associations like [MST151 structure].
However, as I thought, mapping the associations gives an error.

How should the association be made in the above composite key identification structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use embedded keys as below:

```
@Embeddable
public class Mst151Key implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
  private String itemId;

  @Column(name = "COMP_ID")
  private String compId;

  @Column(name = "PRICE_REV")
  private int priceRev;

  @Column(name = "PRICE_TYPE")
  private String priceType;

}

public class MST151 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Mst151Key mst151Key;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_STD")
    private double priceStd;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_UNIT")
    private String priceUnit;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_TYPE")
    private String deliveryType;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_DAY")
    private int deleveryDay;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER")
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_USER")
    private String updateUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TIME")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Column(name = "USED")
    private int used;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MST110 mst110;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMP_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MST150 mst150;
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)